# "Cookbook apache_wrapper not found" when running chefspec in apache_wrapper cookbook

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm new in chef spec and try to figure out how to use unit testing in my cookbooks.
I have installed chefdk(v2 and v3 on different ubuntu instances) and knife spec plugin.
After "apache_wrapper" cookbook creation I have changed next files:

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'chefspec'
require 'chefspec/berkshelf'

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.log_level = :debug
  config.platform = 'ubuntu'
  config.version = '12.04'
end
```

spec/recipes/default_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe 'apache_wrapper::default' do
  subject { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }

  it 'includes community cookbook apache2' do
    expect(subject).to include_recipe('apache2')
  end

  it 'creates a template with attributes' do
    expect(subject).to create_template('/var/www/html/index.html').with(
      user:   'root',
      group:  'root',
      backup: true,
    )

    expect(subject).to_not create_template('/var/www/html/index.html').with(
      user:   'bacon',
      group:  'fat',
      backup: true,
    )
  end
end
```

in my recipe default.eb:

```
include_recipe 'apache2'

template "/var/www/html/index.html" do
  source "index.html.erb"
  mode 00644
end
```

But when I invoke rspec I got next:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/apache_wrapper
$ rspec
...
Failures:

  1) apache_wrapper::default includes community cookbook apache2
     Failure/Error: subject { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }
     Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound:
       Cookbook apache_wrapper not found. If you're loading apache_wrapper from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
     # ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) apache_wrapper::default creates a template with attributes
     Failure/Error: subject { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }
     Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound:
       Cookbook apache_wrapper not found. If you're loading apache_wrapper from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
     # ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.32355 seconds (files took 2.39 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:26 # apache_wrapper::default includes community cookbook apache2
rspec ./spec/recipes/default_spec.rb:30 # apache_wrapper::default creates a template with attributes
```

And in cookbook folder Berksfile.lock appeared.
Can anybody told me what Im doing wrong?

UPD:

Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"
cookbook 'apache2', '= 1.9.6'
```

Berksfile.lock

```
DEPENDENCIES
  apache2 (= 1.9.6)

GRAPH
  apache2 (1.9.6)
    iptables (>= 0.0.0)
    logrotate (>= 0.0.0)
    pacman (>= 0.0.0)
  iptables (0.14.0)
  logrotate (1.7.0)
  pacman (1.1.1)
```

UPD2:

```
cat ../apache_wrapper/metadata.rb | grep -E 'dep|nam'
name             'apache_wrapper'
depends 'apache2'
```

UPD3:

also I tried to use next

```
let (:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new.converge 'apache_wrapper::default' }
```

and now receive

```
Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: apache_wrapper

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* apache_wrapper::default

F

Failures:

  1) apache_wrapper::default includes community cookbook apache2
     Failure/Error: let (:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new.converge 'apache_wrapper::default' }
     Net::HTTPServerException:
       412 "Precondition Failed "
     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

I don't understand, what Im doing wrong, today I've started new instans, install there ruby2.1 and all gems like chefspec and others. And now use rake to run tests, but still getting same error

SOLUTION:
Just add "metadata" to cookbooks Berksfile

Comment: Please post both Berksfile and Berksfile.lock

Comment: Try adding `metadata` as a third line in your Berksfile.  Also, `cookbooks_path` should not be used if you're using the `chefspec/berkshelf` plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify "apache2" as dependency in your cookbooks `metadata.rb` :

```
name             'COOKBOOK NAME'
maintainer       'YOUR NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
...

version          '0.0.1'

depends          'apache2'
```

After that you can include recipes from "apache2" in your cookbook.

**UPDATE:**

Also you need to specify where your "apache_wrapper" cookbook is located, please check chefspec's [configuration options](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#configuration) for more info

**UPDATE 2**

Add `metadata` to your Berksfile, with that in place Berkshelf will add your local cookbook to List of local cookbooks.

From berkshelf.com:

> The metadata keyword is like saying gemspec in Bundler’s Gemfile. It says, “There is a metadata.rb file within the same relative path of my Berksfile”. This allows you to resolve a Cookbook’s dependencies that you are currently working on just like you would resolve the dependencies of a Gem that you are currently working on with Bundler.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already set depends and name, also config.cookbook_path set to folder which contains cookbook apache_wrapper

Comment: Have you tried to run your tests with different runner like:

`  subject { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new.converge(described_recipe) }`

It seems that ChefSpec::SoloRuner [is depricated](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/master/lib/chefspec/deprecations.rb#L18).

Comment: Yes, also I tried to use next 
`let (:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new.converge 'apache_wrapper::default' } `
and now receive 
`Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: apache_wrapper`
412 "Precondition Failed " 
I don't understand, what Im doing wrong, today I've started new instans, install there ruby2.1 and all gems kice chefspec and others.

Comment: Can you try to move your cookbook to "./cookbooks" dir, and remove custom cookbooks_path settings, on that way, you should have "default" chef directory structure.

Comment: I think that i have founded issue, can you try to update your Berksfile to be like this https://gist.github.com/rastasheep/e600fad6d7e37a0da90a (check path of your local cookbook). After that install cookbooks something like "berks vendor vendor/cookbooks" and set cookbook_path to same location "vendor/cookbooks". With that in place you;ll have all necessary cookbooks on same place "vendor/cookbooks".

Comment: I think it's wierd to add testing cookbook in Berksfile, but it seems working for me.
Anyway I'll try to find out how to fix this issue without adding path to testing cookbook to Berksfile. Because I have a lot of cookbooks with difficult Berksfile structure, with root Berksfile like `source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"

metadata

def dependencies(path)
  berks = "#{path}/Berksfile"
  instance_eval(File.read(berks)) if File.exists?(berks)
end

Dir.glob('./cookbooks/*').each do |path|
  dependencies path
  cookbook File.basename(path), :path => path
end`

Comment: Another option is to add "metadata" to your Berksfile as  @Tejay Cardon suggested instead of explicit cookbook name and path.

Comment: Yes! It is! Im just need to add "metadata" to my Berksfile. Thank You and Thanks to @Tejay Cardon