# Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[enable mod_proxy for apache-tomcat binding]'

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, berkshelf

I am using [this github repo](https://github.com/gitsubham/testrepo.git) to understand the working of Berkshelf when used along with Amazon Opsworks. The basic idea behind what i am trying is if i mention apache2 as a dependency in berksfile for my *phpapp recipe* then it will automatically manage the dependencies for *apache2* which itself is a dependency for phpapp. when i try this with AWS opsworks i get the following error.

```
   ================================================================================
   Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[enable mod_proxy for apache-tomcat binding]'
   ================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/sbin/a2enmod proxy ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR: Module proxy does not exist!
---- End output of /usr/sbin/a2enmod proxy ----
Ran /usr/sbin/a2enmod proxy returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_java/recipes/apache_tomcat_bind.rb

1: execute 'enable mod_proxy for apache-tomcat binding' do
2:   command '/usr/sbin/a2enmod proxy'
3:   not_if do
4:     ::File.symlink?(::File.join(node['apache']['dir'], 'mods-enabled', 'proxy.load')) || node['opsworks_java']['tomcat']['apache_tomcat_bind_mod'] !~ /\Aproxy/
5:   end
6: end
7: 



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_java/recipes/apache_tomcat_bind.rb:1:in `from_file'

execute("enable mod_proxy for apache-tomcat binding") do
action "run"
retries 0
retry_delay 2
command "/usr/sbin/a2enmod proxy"
backup 5
returns 0
cookbook_name "opsworks_java"
recipe_name "apache_tomcat_bind"
not_if { #code block }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `metadata` insted of `cookbook "apache2"`  to your Berksfile, with that in place Berkshelf will add your local cookbook to list of local cookbooks, and it's dependencies from `metadata.rb`

From berkshelf.com:

```
The metadata keyword is like saying gemspec in Bundler’s Gemfile. It says,
“There is a metadata.rb file within the same relative path of my Berksfile”.
This allows you to resolve a Cookbook’s dependencies that you are currently
working on just like you would resolve the dependencies of a Gem that 
you are currently working on with Bundler.
```

Here is [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976081/cookbook-apache-wrapper-not-found-when-running-chefspec-in-apache-wrapper-cook).

Comment: Hmm it seems that mod_proxy isn't included in default_modules, you can include it with `include_recipe 'apache2::mod_proxy'`.

Btw i have founded that resource from your log is not in you cookbook, but it's in some ["opsworks-example-cookbooks" repo]( https://github.com/amazonwebservices/opsworks-example-cookbooks/blob/master/tomcat/recipes/apache_tomcat_bind.rb#L14) is maybe that left over on your instance/runlist ?

Comment: also i didnt understand, where do i need to make the changes ? as in where should i add these lines "include_recipe 'apache2::mod_proxy'"

Comment: In your recipe just below `include_recipe "apache2"` line, because default recipe setups apache2 and all other recipes from apache2 cookbook will just add mods on top of it.

Comment: But please check your nodes runlist, because resource 'execute[enable mod_proxy for apache-tomcat binding]' is not in your cookbook, from where is that included?

Comment: i tried that both ways above it and below it but both of them didnt work.

Comment: can we please discuss it in chat because i am kind of stuck badly ?

Comment: i have mentioned the run list in the custom json textbox of stack in opsworks like ->  {"run_list":["recipe[phpapp]"]}, but after adding that it showed another error being run_list attribute not properly used. where to put the run_list in opsworks ?

Comment: OpsWorks has specific way of managing runlists it's [described here]( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-assigningcustom.html).

Comment: oh.. that i am already doing, in my custom recipe section of the layer, i have added phpapp::default in setup lifecycle.

Comment: Can you try to use Ubuntu instead Amazon Linux, there is some reports on web that this happens only on Amazon Linux?

Comment: ya i tried that too but that is also giving errors well they are different than the one amazon linux gives !